# how can i speed up mysql query when using running a select using a count(distinct ) query

Tags: mysql, performance, count, distinct

Can someone please tell me how I can use speed up this mysql query. I know it's currently running slow due to the count(distinct subcontractorRef) syntax. Any other alternatives?

```
SELECT DISTINCT (contractorsRef) AS cref, RIDGROUP AS ridg,  
    (select count(DISTINCT subcontractorRef) 
    FROM request 
    INNER JOIN request_config ON request_config.RIDGROUP = request.RIDGROUP 
    WHERE request_config.contractorsRef = outer_config.contractorsRef  
    AND currenttaxyear =2011 
    AND weekno =31) AS xxx 
FROM request_config outer_config 
WHERE currenttaxyear =2011 
AND weekno =32 
AND contractorsRef <>132
```

Comment: Please post the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`, `SHOW CREATE TABLE request_config` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE request`.

Comment: First answer on all database speedup questions: indexes. Have you tried them?

Answer (score 1):

Try this using a JOIN instead of a subquery:

```
SELECT
    contractorsRef AS cref,
    RIDGROUP AS ridg,
    IFNULL(T1.subcontractorCount, 0) AS xxx
FROM request_config AS outer_config
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        request_config.contractorsRef,
        COUNT(DISTINCT subcontractorRef) AS subcontractorCount
    FROM request 
    INNER JOIN request_config
    ON request_config.RIDGROUP = request.RIDGROUP 
    AND currenttaxyear = 2011 
    AND weekno = 31
    GROUP BY contractorsRef
) T1
ON T1.contractorsRef = outer_config.contractorsRef 
WHERE currenttaxyear = 2011 
AND weekno = 32 
AND contractorsRef <> 132
GROUP BY outer_config.contractorsRef
```

Comment: this works, but it's the same speed as if I was to do it the other way. How can I incorporate the count(*) and then using distinct, as I read thats a faster way than count(distinct xx)?

Comment: @user984314: Have you tried adding any indexes? An index on `(currenttaxyear, weekno)` might help.

Answer (score 0):

A guess since we dont know any indexes. But a very common mistake is too not have an index covering al the tables in the where clause.
example from your outer select:

FROM request_config 
WHERE currenttaxyear =2011 
AND weekno =32 
AND contractorsRef <>132

Then you need an index:
create index mynewIndex on request_config(currenttaxyear,weekno,contractorsRef)
the order of the columns in that index can make a big difference. So try to change them around abit.

Comment: then i need to se more info on indexesm queryplans and the tables to be of more help